# how to get date of monday of current week

Tags: android

how to get date of monday of current week instead of sunday below is my code which give me output with times i dont want times

```
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
    cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

    // get start of this week in milliseconds
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    Log.d(tag,"Start of this week :       " + cal.getTime());



       this give output likr this

      Sun Sep 08 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2013


   and i wan to get like this
     Mon Sep9 2013   only
```

Answer (score 0):

Week's begining depends on location accroding to documentation. But in your case I suggest using `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);` to get needed output

Comment: is nice it wil give output like this
Mon Sep 09 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2013   how do i filter this prgramicay to get only  09  date of monday only???

Comment: `.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`

Comment: u mean remove Calendar.Nonday??

Comment: no, i mean get it like so... `SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d yyyy"); System.out.println(date_format.format(cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));`

Comment: Scratch that, the answer by Lalit's pretty much the same, though i disagree with manually setting first day.

Answer (score -1):

In Calendar week start from Sunday, so get second day instead of first to get Monday.

Comment: tell me where i chnge the code? i didnot se anything where is set Sunday

Comment: i have only date like 9/11/2013   tell me any function where i put this date and get first day of currentweek date